# Copy data from one workbook to another "Object Required"

Tags: excel, vba, object, paste

I'm currently doing VBA project which need to copy from a workbook to another, which the `WBookPst` is the workbook I firstly open (use) meanwhile `WBookCopy` is the workbook where I open based on the links where I got by listing all ".xslt" format in a File into my Sheet1 of my first workbook. Here is my code :

```
Sub SortFiles()
    'Set up your variables and turn off screen updating.
    'Dim iCounter As Integer
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Sort the rows based on the data in column C
    Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), _
    order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim WBookCopy As Workbook
    Dim WBookPst As Workbook
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim sheetCopy As Worksheet
    Dim sheetPate As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim rngPst As Range

    filePath = Range("B2").Value
    Set WBookCopy = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    Columns(30).Insert
    For i = 1 To Sheets.count
        Cells(i, 30) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

    sheetName = Range("AD1").Value
    Set sheetCopy = WBookCopy.Worksheets(sheetName)
    Set rngCopy = sheetCopy.Range("A:AA").Copy

    Set WBookPst = ThisWorkbook
    Set sheetPaste = WBookPst.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set rngCopy = sheetPaste.Range("A:AA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

At `Set rngCopy = sheetCopy.Range("A:AA").Copy` there's error "Objects required".

What does that mean?
By the way, is how I copy and paste the data between sheets correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `rngCopy` is of type range and you can't set it equal to a method (copy). Remove the `.Copy` and you should be fine. You also don't need to set the worksheet out range to a variable. You could just do one line that says `WBookCopy.SheetName.Range("A:AA").Copy`and then another line to paste.

Comment: Thanks! It does remove the error but I dont know how to paste the value to my first-opened Workbook. Is it my coding (as above) correct?

Answer (score 0):

As @Wyatt mentioned - your copy\paste syntax is incorrect

Here are 2 ways to do it:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AA").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AA").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Comment: The answer from @paul answers your question about how to paste the data. Feel free to mark whichever answer is appropriate

Comment: @wyatt did solve the error! And thanks Paul for helping! :)